# How to use a formula while pasting values with .Range.Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a dynamic range data from one Worksheet to another using VBA but in some of the columns I need to use weighted_average*Quantity instead of copying Quantity directly.

From first sheet Past :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DCE | ABC | 100 | 400 |
| CBA | XYZ | 200 | 500 |
| XYA | CED | 300 | 600 |

To second sheet Present :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DCE | ABC | 200 | 600 |
| CBA | XYZ | 400 | 750 |
| XYA | CED | 600 | 900 |

Here the weighted average is being taken by another sheet which is 2 in Case of col C and 1.5 in Case of Col D

```
Sub Calc()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim N As Long
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Past")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Present")
    
    

    With wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("A9").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    With wsData.Range("B2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("B9").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
    With wsData.Range("C2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("C9").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value *(F7/F6)
    End With
    With wsData.Range("D2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        wsDest.Range("D9").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value * (G7/G6)
    End With
```

This is not working but I cant find the correct syntax with .Value to multiply with my existing value!

Thank you, let me know if I can explain better.

Comment: You're working with the `.Value` of a multi-cell range, which is an array. Use a loop over the individual array elements to multiply them by the weighted average.

Comment: But then how do I get the dynamic range, if I use lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row, it wont be dynamic right, wont delete or automatically refresh if something is changed in Past sheet!

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal is exactly, but if you need a formula, you need to write an actual formula... `=...` to the range.

Comment: Sorry, I think the end goal is the code that you gave, it is just giving me a type mismatch error when I run and I am trying to find if I did something wrong, will update in a bit

Comment: If you get a type mismatch, you're likely trying to perform a mathematical operation on something non-numeric.

Comment: Thanks, it was the earlier loop giving other col number, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with the `.Value` of a multi-cell range, which is an array. Use a loop over the array to multiply each element by the weighted average.

```
With wsData
    Dim avg1 As Double, avg2 As Double
    avg1 = .Range("F7").Value / .Range("F6").Value
    avg2 = .Range("G7").Value / .Range("G6").Value

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = .Range("C2:D" & lastRow).Value
End With
    
Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(arr, 1) to Ubound(arr, 1)
    arr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1) * avg1
    arr(i, 2) = arr(i, 2) * avg2
Next

wsDest.Range("C9").Resize(Ubound(arr, 1), 2).Value = arr
```